# Create new dataframe using "VLOOKUP" between two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Somewhat similar to Excel's VLOOKUP function, I am wanting to use a value in one dataframe (`portfolios` below) to find an associated value in a second dataframe (`returns` below) and populate a third dataframe (let's call this dataframe3 for now) with these returned values.  I have found several posts based on left merges and `map`, but my original two dataframes are of different structures, so these methods don't seem to fit (to me, at least).

I haven't made much progress, but here is the code I have:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

portfolios = pd.read_csv('portstst5_1.csv')
returns = pd.read_csv('Example_Returns.csv')

total_cols = len(portfolios.columns)
headers = list(portfolios)

concat = returns['PERMNO'].map(str) + returns['FROMDATE'].map(str)
idx = 2
returns.insert(loc=idx, column="concat", value=concat)

for i in range(total_cols):
    col_len = portfolios.iloc[:,i].count()
    for j in range(col_len):
        print(portfolios.iat[j,i].astype('int').astype('str') + headers[i])
```

**Data**

This code will make a little more sense if I first describe my data:
`portfolios` is a dataframe with 13 columns of varying lengths.  The column headers are dates in YYYYMMDD format.  Below each date header are identifiers which are five digit numeric codes.  A snippet of `portfolios` looks like this (some elements in some columns contain NaN):

```
    20131231  20131130  20131031  20130930  20130831  20130731  20130630  \
0    93044.0   93044.0   13264.0   13264.0   89169.0   82486.0   91274.0   
1    79702.0   91515.0   90710.0   81148.0   47387.0   88359.0   93353.0   
2    85751.0   85724.0   88810.0   11513.0   85576.0   47387.0   85576.0
```

The data in `returns` data originally consists of three columns and 799 rows and looks like this (all elements are populated with values):

```
     PERMNO  FROMDATE     MORET
0     93044  20131231 -0.022304
1     79702  20131231  0.012283
2     85751  20131231 -0.016453
3     85576  20131231  0.038766
```

**Desired Output**

I would like to make a third dataframe that is structured identically to `portfolios`.  That is, it will have the same column header dates and the same number of rows in each column as does `portfolios`, but instead of identifiers, it will contain the `MORET` for the appropriate identifier/date combination.  This is the reason for the concatenations in my code above - I am trying (perhaps unnecessarily) to create unique lookup values so I can communicate between `portfolios` and `returns`.  For example, to populate `dataframe3[0,0]`, I would look for the concatenated values from `portfolios[0,0]` and `headers[0]` (i.e. 9304420131231) in `returns['concat']` and return the associated value in `returns['MORET']` (i.e. -0.022304).  I am stuck here on how to use the concatenated values to return my desired data.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IIUC:**

Using a combination of [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) so the we can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) values from `returns` by desired columns. Then use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) to reshape the data back, as seen below.

```
portfolios.columns = portfolios.columns.astype(int)
newdf = portfolios.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index',var_name=['FROMDATE'],value_name='PERMNO').merge(returns,on=['FROMDATE','PERMNO'],how='left').pivot(index='index',columns='FROMDATE',values='MORET')
```

Which returnsthe DataFrame below

```
FROMDATE  20130630  20130731  20130831  20130930  20131031  20131130  20131231
index
0              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.022304
1              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.012283
2              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.016453
```

---

Sort columns

```
newdf.loc[:,newdf.columns.sort_values(ascending=False)]
```

Comment: When trying this, I am receiving a ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Do you have `NaN` values in you original dataframe? could try and replace `.astype(int)` with `.astype(float)`@CodingNewb

Comment: @CodingNewb, I was using `astype(int)` because the column names were stored as strings, I edited the post to change the column names before the merge, and removed `.astype(int)` from the main line, let me know if this works

Comment: This is fantastic, and I've learned a lot breaking this into parts.  One final question:  Is it possible to sort the output with the columns in reverse (descending) order?  My `portfolios` file that I read in is sorted in descending order, but the output of the pivot table is in reverse.  Thank you.

Comment: @CodingNewb, glad to help! I edited the question with code to sort the columns. If I have sufficiently answered your question, consider marking it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Or mark one of the answers that appropriately answers your question

Comment: Thank you!  I am getting this error related to the column sort:  IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds.  However, this sort is beyond the scope of my original question which you fully answered, so I have marked the solution as accepted.  Thanks again!

Comment: @CodingNewb, use `.loc` instead of `iloc`, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is **much** simpler than how you tried doing it. You can first melt `portfolios` to flip it and collect all the date columns as rows in a single column, then join it with `returns`, and finally pivot to get the desired result. This is basically what @djk47463 did in one compound line, and my edited answer serves as a step-by-step breakdown of his.

Let's create your DataFrames to make the answer reproducible.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

# Create df
rawText = StringIO("""
     PERMNO  FROMDATE     MORET
0     93044  20131231 -0.022304
1     79702  20131231  0.012283
2     85751  20131231 -0.016453
3     85576  20131231  0.038766
4     93044  20131010 -0.02
5     79702  20131010  0.01
6     85751  20131010 -0.01
7     85576  20131010  0.03
""")
returns = pd.read_csv(rawText, sep = "\s+")
portfolios = pd.DataFrame({'20131010':[93044, 85751],
                       '20131231':[85576, 79702]})
```

Notice, the `FROMDATE` column of `returns` consists of numbers, but in `portfolios` the date columns are strings. We must make them consistent:

```
df.FROMDATE = df.FROMDATE.astype(str)
```

Let's start the solution by `melt`ing (i.e. unpivot) `portfolios`:

```
portfolios = portfolios.melt(var_name=['FROMDATE'],value_name='PERMNO')
# portfolios: 
   FROMDATE  PERMNO
0  20131010   93044
1  20131010   85751
2  20131231   85576
3  20131231   79702
```

Now you want to hold this `pm` constant, and merge `returns` to its lines whenever their `PERMNO`s and `FROMDATE`s match:

```
merged = pm.merge(df, how='left', on=['PERMNO', 'FROMDATE'])
# merged: 
   FROMDATE  PERMNO     MORET
0  20131010   93044 -0.020000
1  20131010   85751 -0.010000
2  20131231   85576  0.038766
3  20131231   79702  0.012283
```

Remember we had `melt`ed (unpivoted) the `portfolios` at the beginning? We should `pivot` this result to give it the shape of `portfolios`:

```
final = merged.pivot(index='PERMNO', columns='FROMDATE', values='MORET').reset_index()
# final: 
FROMDATE  PERMNO  20131010  20131231
0          79702       NaN  0.012283
1          85576       NaN  0.038766
2          85751     -0.01       NaN
3          93044     -0.02       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for this; the pivot table is very helpful.  However, when I do the intersection, `new_df` is an Empty DataFrame.  One thought I had on why it is empty:  The column headers in `portfolios` are in descending order (20131231, 20131130,etc), but the column headers in `new_df` (prior to the intersection) are in ascending order.  However, I can't figure out how to reverse the column order in the pivot table.  Could this be the reason for the Empty DataFrame?

Comment: Not that, but it can be that the column names of one are strings, and the other numbers. Will be as easy as fixing the `common`. Could you give me the result of `portfolio.columns` and `new_df.columns`? If they are large please give me 5 of each.

Comment: Pretty sure that is the reason. Can you please let me know if this solves it: `common = [e for e in new_df.columns if str(e) in portfolio.columns]` and then you'll again do: `new_df = new_df[common]`.

Comment: Yes - that was the reason.  `portfolios.columns` contains strings: Index(['20131231', '20131130', '20131031', '20130930', '20130831', and `new_df.columns` contains ints: Int64Index([20120131, 20120229, 20120331, 20120430, 20120531,...  The code now returns `new_df` with the correct number of columns, but the columns contain `MORET` for every `PERMNO` with a `MORET` whether or not the `PERMNO` is present in the associated month from `portfolios`. That is, while every `PERMNO` in `returns` has a `MORET` in each `FROMDATE`, not every `PERMNO` exists in every column of `portfolios`.

Comment: @CodingNewb I see your point. I overlooked this final step, it will be better if you don't immediately pivot the `returns`, but first melt `portfolios`, then join with `returns`, then pivot; which is basically what djk47463 did. I'll edit my answer to take care of the full process in small pieces, which will serve as a breakdown and step-by-step explanation, but as the owner of the first complete answer, djk47463 deserves the checkmark. Thank you for the good question!

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do a vlookup in python is to create a series with what would be your left column in the index, and then slice that series by the lookup value. The NaNs complicate it a little. We'll make a series from `returns` by using the `set_index` method to set `PERMNO` as the index for the dataframe, and then slicing by the column name to isolate the `MORET` column as a series.

```
lookupseries = returns.set_index('PERMNO')['MORET']
def lookup(x):
    try: 
        return lookupseries[x]
    except: 
        return np.nan
newdf = portfolios.copy()
for c in newdf.columns:
    newdf[c] = newdf[c].apply(lookup)
```